# Show/hide HTML element when custom field is empty

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, show-hide, custom-fields

I have custom fields on the page which are gathered from the user input on the form. Every time there will be inserted ONLY ONE (`customfield1` and `customfield2`). I don't know how to hide the whole `div` (class="customfield") if the `customfield1` or `customfield2` is empty. I cannot change `customfield` to different class or id.

Thank you very much!

```
<div class="customfield">
    <h4>Custom field title 1</h4>
    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield1", true) ): ?>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield1", true); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>                     
</div>

<div class="customfield">
    <h4>Custom field title 2</h4>
    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield2", true) ): ?>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield2", true); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>                     
</div>
```

Comment: At what point do you want to hide the other custom field?  Can we have the html that is actually output?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Explosion Pills - the php outputs just the data entered, raw data. I want to hide the whole class="customfield" where there is no data in the customfield, or at least h4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".customfield").filter(function () {
   return $.trim($('p', this).text()) === '';
}).hide();​
```

This will hide all `.customfield` elements containing a `<p>` that has no text.

Comment: hmm, this hides all of the custom fields, even those with value

Comment: @MP if you show me some example html (with values filled in) I can run it against my code and debug it.

Comment: @MP I thought that the custom field was an input.  Use `.text` instead of `.val`.  Also wrap it in `<p></p>` as you suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/C47kx/3/

Comment: Perfect! Works like it should! Thank you very much!